# mat sort works one time and then gives error

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a dynamic mat table with sort

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<MemberList>;
  @Output() walkthroughData: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  data: any;
  memberList: MemberList[];
  membersCount: number;
ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });

    this.teamService.getTeamMembers().subscribe((response) => {
      this.data = response['data']['result'];

      this.memberList = this.data.map(({ name, role, email }) => ({
        teamMember: Object.values(name).join(' '),
        email,
        role: role?.name,
        assignedOn: [
          'LA Care Health Plan',
          'LA Care Health Plan',
          'LA Care Health Plan',
        ],
      }));
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.memberList);
    });
  }
```

It works only single time and then throws error

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined
```

What I am doing wrong?
matHeaderCellDef and matCellDef are same, mat sort module is also imported and i have also tried ngAfterViewInit for the datasource but same error comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a race-condition issue, the first time is working by a coincidence.
Your setTimeout is executing before your subscribe, this way, your dataSource variable isn't defined yet.

You should move this code:

```
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

To set right after your variable is instantiated:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.memberList);
```

Comment: the sorting error is gone but again works for the first time only